# Access to argv[1] blocks the program

Tags: c

I'm trying to get an ip address from the command line, so I prepared a simple parser. The problem is that the program seems to stop when I try to read from argv[i].

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
unsigned char packet[1500];
int n,len,i,j;
unsigned char dstmac[6];
unsigned char targetip[4];
unsigned char * add;
unsigned char byte=0;

if(argc==2){
        j=0;
        i=0;
        add = argv[1];
        printf(">>%s<< \n",add);
        fflush(stdout);
        printf("%c ",add[1]);
        fflush(stdout);
        while(add[i]) {
                printf("%c ",add[i]);
                fflush(stdout);
                if( add[i] != '.' )
                        byte = byte*10+(add[i]-48);
                else{
                        targetip[j++] = byte;
                        byte=0;
                }
                i++;
        }
        targetip[j++]=byte;
}
else{
        targetip[0]=88;
        targetip[1]=80;
        targetip[2]=187;
        targetip[3]=50;
}

printf("TARGET IP: %d.%d.%d.%d",targetip[0],targetip[1],targetip[2],targetip[3]);
fflush(stdout);

struct eth_frame * eth;
struct ip_datagram * ip;
struct icmp_packet * icmp;

//etc.....
```

I really don't know why. Can you help me?

EDIT: update code with fflush(stdout)

ACTUAL OUTPUT:

```
1238166@localhost:~/ping$ gcc ping2.c -o np
1238166@localhost:~/ping$ ./np 216.58.205.67
>>216.58.205.67<<
1
2 1 6 . 5 8 . 2 0 5 . 6 7 TARGET IP: 216.58.205.67
```

now the programm blocks when it prints the "TARGET IP". 
In the rest of the programm there is the pakcet initialization and exchange. I have already tested this part and it should work.

UPDATE: what I noticed is that the program now needs an ffflush(stdout) to go on, but before this was not necessary. If I run for example without arguments (the else clause), all works properly.

```
1238166@localhost:~/ping$ ./np
TARGET IP: 88.80.187.50destmac: f2(242) 3c(060) 91(145) 2c(044)
53(083) b7(183)
 ================
SENT PACKET:

f2(242) 3c(060) 91(145) 2c(044)
53(083) b7(183) ....
```

Comment: Why print `add[1]`? It starts at `add[0]`.

Comment: In your final `printf` add a `\n` so the output will be flushed. Maybe it doesn't block but doesn't flush.

Comment: add `fflush(stdout);` after your prints

Comment: @user3121023 I've update with output,

Comment: @pmg I added fflush(), now I can see the printing, but the program still stops.

Comment: You should not use magic numbers in your code. Escpecially not if you initially mean ASCII values of characters. Just use `'0'` instead of `48`. This will work with all character encodings.

Comment: @Bach05 you are still missing a fflush after the last printf, or add a \n at the end of the format string.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie They are only octal if you start with `0`. The common `192.168...` is `0xC0,0xA8,...`

Comment: @chmike you are right, I've update but the problem still there: after printing the program stops and waits.

Comment: @user3121023 I've already tested the second part (it's packet exchange) and it should work.

Comment: @user3121023 Well, my idea is that it needs an `fflush()` every time it prints. But for example if i run the program without arguments 8the else clause) it works properly.

Comment: @user3121023 It works! That's a problem on the gateway. Now I got it, thanks! I was messing up because I didn't understand why it didn't print anything in the parsing. That's strange...

Comment: Using a `struct in_addr` is probably nicer to use to store an IP address (if you use correct byte order). Even better: consider parsing the IP address using `getaddrinfo`. It will parse IPv4 addresses, but it will also resolve host names.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried your program, it didn’t block. The program terminates.

However, the instructions `printf("%c ",add[1]);` and `printf("%c ",add[i]);` had no visible effect. This is because the character is buffered and not printed to the console. The buffered content is out put to the console when a `fflush(stdout);` is performed. Printf does this itself when there is a `\n` in the output string. The buffer content is also output to the console when the program terminates on Linux.

When I run your program with the argument `123.45.67.255`, I get the single line output `2 1 2 3 . 4 5 . 6 7 . 2 5 5 TARGET IP: 123.45.67.255` which is what it is supposed to be.

The output you see is Windows specific.Apparently, on Windows the buffer content is not flushed when the program terminates. You must add a \n at the end of the format string of the last printf.

Note: modifying the question after the question is answered make the answer confusing.